# Инклуд не реагирует на основной контент

Tags: php

Включил инклудом файл в страницу. Возник вопрос - инклуд работает автономно или всё же взаимодействует со всем контентом?

Что не получается (пример)

```
если юзер авторизован, i=1

инклудим файл, в котором условие если i=1 то вывести "Авторизован"
```

Ничего не происходит, поэтому и задаю такой вопрос.

Comment: Подключенный файл получает ту же область видимости, что и контекст, из которого он был вызван. Если он подключается через http, то я уже писал, почему у вас не получится вообще ничего.

Comment: Вы правы, убрал http заработало. Хотя allow_url_include On. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, а я уже писал. Потому что когда запрос идет по хттп, он идет по сетке и обрабатывается сервером, ровно как если из браузера запросить. Сервер выполняет php, поэтому приходит уже исполненный файл без всяких переменных и php-тегов, просто как html.

Ей-богу, ну если появился вопрос про различия запроса файлов - если не разберитесь в вопросе до появления ясности, то хотя бы комментарии прочтите.

Comment: Спасибо за толковый ответ!